# How to Conditionally Skip tearDown for Webdriver tests

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I'm making a few simple selenium tests using Python 3 and the unittest module. I'm wondering if there is a way to not run the tearDown function between every test? I understand I could simply omit the tearDown completely from the class, but this will not return results on every test result. Also, if I were to write the 2nd test where the first test leaves off, I am given an exception stating that the Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver Session.
Below is my current code. In the following example, I basically write the second test, containing the steps from the first. This is what I'd like to avoid.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class Login_Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    username = 'XXXX'
    password = 'XXXX'

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari()

    def test_1_LogIn(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('PRIVATE URL')
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.find_element_by_id('j_id0:eCommerceSiteTemplate:j_id14:username').send_keys(self.username)
        driver.find_element_by_id('j_id0:eCommerceSiteTemplate:j_id14:password').send_keys(self.password, '\n')
        time.sleep(4)
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="globalHeaderNameMink"]/span/text()').text
        self.assertIn('Chris GExecutive', element)

    def test_2_Store_Load(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('PRIVATE URL')
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.find_element_by_id('j_id0:eCommerceSiteTemplate:j_id14:username').send_keys(self.username)
        driver.find_element_by_id('j_id0:eCommerceSiteTemplate:j_id14:password').send_keys(self.password, '\n')
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '#bodyCell > div:nth-child(9) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(4) > h2 > a').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'body > div.container.hidden-phone.deskLayout > header > div.row-fluid.headerRow > '
            'div > div.top_navigation > p > span > span.loginoutsec > a').text
        self.assertIn('Logout', elem)


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do that. Each test should be independent and a full test. If you find that you are repeating code in multiple tests then you should start using the page object model or create some functions so you can increase your code reuse.